# Using an iterator to go through a vector and modify the contents

Tags: c++, iterator

I am stuck on a practice problem from the C++ primer. I must use an iterator to cycle through an initialized vector and square each element, then output each altered element.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


using std::vector; 
using std::cout;


int main()
{

    vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    vector<int>::iterator i;
    for (auto i =v.begin();  i != v.end(); i++)   
        i *= i;

    for (auto i =v.begin(); i < v.end; i++)     
        cout << i << " "; 
    cout << endl;
}
```

I keep getting this message:

[Error] no match for 'operator<' (operand types are '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >' and '')

Comment: You want to handle the element, not the iterator. Try `*i *= *i;` and `cout << *i << " ";`.

Comment: Or use ranged-for, ex: `for (auto& i : v)`

Comment: `vector<int>::iterator i;` is not used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have forgotten parenteces here (after the `v.end`):

```
    for (auto i =v.begin(); i < v.end; i++)
```

Next, in these two lines you define the variable with the same name, thus overriding one with the other:

```
    vector<int>::iterator i;
    for (auto i =v.begin();  i != v.end(); i++)
```

What did you mean by that: `i *= i;`?

Maybe you ment `*i *= *i`?

And finally,

```
    cout << i << " ";
```

If you want to output the value, try

```
    cout << *i << " ";
```

Comment: Silly me, such simple mistakes. Now the compiler is telling me "no match for 'operator *='..."

Comment: Please show the exact line your compiler complains on. Have you dereferenced the iterator? `*i *= *i`

Comment: 15 9 [Error] no match for 'operator*=' (operand types are 'int' and '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >')     Its line 15. The program compiles when I used your suggestion to us *i *= *i, but now its giving me random numbers.

Comment: @AKO There are plenty of errors in your initial program. I cannot discuss your corrections without seeing your current version. Please provide the update.

Comment: ``#include <iostream> #include <vector> using std::vector; using std::cout; using std::endl; int main() { vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}; for (auto i =v.begin(); i != v.end(); i++) *i *= i; for (auto i =v.begin(); i < v.end(); i++) cout << *i < " "; cout << endl; }``

Comment: @AKO Please read my post CAREFULLY. Each symbol is important. My advice was: `*i *= *i`, no more, no less.

Comment: @AKO The program you provided doesn't compile. There is one more misprint: should be `cout << *i << " ";` instead of `cout << *i < " ";`.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect place for [*range-based* for loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

```
for (auto& e : v) {
   e *= e;
}

for (const auto& e : v) {
   std::cout << e << " ";
}
```

Comment: Agreed, but I would like to solve this problem which requires the use of iterators.